# How can I mount a Gitlab ci/cd cache into a Docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

How can I make a Gitlab ci/cd cache available inside a Docker container?

I have a build script like this:

```
dependency-check:
  image: maven:3-openjdk-11
  stage: verify
  cache:
    - key: downloads
      paths:
        - ./downloads
  script:
    - ...
  ...
```

What do I have to add, in order to mount the cache `downloads` into the container, write files to it and re-use it in future pipelines?

Comment: Just to be sure: using *Docker-in-Docker* ? Do you have a specific usage of containers in your pipeline (your `script` section) ?

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't realize that the paths refers to a directory inside my working directory, which is already available in the docker container. (I did not even speak about Docker-in-Docker.)

Answer (score 1):

A *cache item* corresponds to regular files or directories on the filesystem that GitLab will cache.

If you need to cache a file/directory that is generated from a running container, use a **volume**:

```yaml
dependency_check:
    ...
    script:
        - docker run  -v $(pwd)/downloads:/some/dir your_image
```

> Using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), the directory will be cached after the first pipeline, and will already exist for the next pipelines. This is useful when running something in the container, to avoid your application regenerating a directory that it should keep.

If you just need to get a file/directory from a container, you could just [copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_cp/) from the container:

```yaml
dependency_check:
    ...
    script:
        - docker create --name your_container your_image
        - rm -rf ./downloads
        - docker cp your_container:/some/dir/ ./downloads
```

> Here the container is [created but not started](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/). This is useful if you build your image in this step, to avoid regenerating a directory that it could reuse, by sending it to the build context.

Here is a blog post I wrote if that helps too:
[Using cache in GitLab CI with Docker-in-Docker](https://aymdev.io/en/blog/post/using-cache-in-gitlab-ci-with-docker-in-docker)